# How to properly setup SignalR project

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am creating a dashboard application that utilizes SignalR. The application will have two screens, one a dashboard screen to see statistics for the whole population and another view that will be statistics for a specific population subset.

When the statistics change for a specific population subset what is the best way to only send a message to clients who are on the view for that specific subset? Do I utilize groups for each subset or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups are definitely your best friends there.